# MutableSharedFlow of list unexpectedly updates a separate plain Kotlin list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

this code runs on desktop using [compose multiplatform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb) but I guess it would work on android the same way.

```
class MyData{
  var x: Int = -1
}

object Repo {
  val allData = (0..10).map { MyData().apply { x=it } }
  val mySharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<List<MyData>>(1)
}
```

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
  // initialize with some data from `Repo.allData`
  Repo.mySharedFlow.emit(Repo.allData.take(5))
  application {
     Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        MainScreen()
     }
  }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
  val currlist = Repo.mySharedFlow.collectAsState(emptyList())
  val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
  Column {
     currlist.value.forEach { Text(it.x.toString()) }

     Button({
        scope.launch {
          val newList = currlist.value.toMutableList()
          newList[0].x = 500 // changes the original `allData`
//        newList[0] = newList[0].apply { x=500 } // changes the original `allData`
//        newList[0] = MyData().apply { x=500 } // Does not change the original `allData`

          Repo.mySharedFlow.emit(newList.plus(MyData())) //optional: added new element just to force recomposition
        }
     }) { Text("modify list") }
     
     // A button to print `allData`
     Button({ scope.launch { println(Repo.allData.map { it.x }) } }) { Text("print allData") }

  }
}
```

as you can see when I click "modify list" button I'm trying to modify an item in the composable state `currlist` but when I check the original list `Repo.allData` I find that it changed as well !! why ? I also noticed that using `newList[0] = MyData().apply { x=500 }` doesn't cause `Repo.allData` to change ! , this is weird for me, I thought that when I initialized the flow with `Repo.mySharedFlow.emit(Repo.allData.take(5))` I was creating a completely new list indepedent from `Repo.allData` , I hope I formulated the issue correctly, can some one explain to me why `allData` changes in the first place and then why it didn't change when using `newList[0] = MyData().apply { x=500 }` ?

Edit: explained by @Tenfour04 , thanks, it had nothing to do with flows:

```
  println(Repo.allData.map { it.x })
//[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  val mlist = Repo.allData.take(5).toMutableList()
  mlist[0].x=500
  println(Repo.allData.map { it.x })
//[500, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you copied the list using `toMutableList()`, it wasn’t a deep copy. Both old and new lists are referencing (pointing at) the same item instances. You are mutating one of those shared item instances.

When you call the constructor you put a new item instance in the new list, so you are not mutating a shared item instance.

Side note, you should avoid ever putting a mutable class (one with any `var` properties) in a StateFlow. That is very error prone. StateFlow is always comparing old and new values when it gets new values, so it will get messed up if the old value is getting modified out from under it.

Comment: thanks, so `Iterable<T>.take` doesn't create a new instance as well ? and a new instance was only created when replacing an item in the list ? , also about the side note, would `@stable` annotation and overriding `equals` be enough ?

Comment: thanks, accepted the answer and edited the post, this - probably basic knowledge - blows my mind though, is there a way to deep copy a list without adding, removing or replacing an item in it ?

Comment: `take` doesn't create a deep copy either. I don't know how `@Stable` would have anything to do with this. Overriding `equals` cannot remove mutability. That would just make things even more error prone if you use it to try to mask that a mutated class was not mutated. In general, you should avoid making your data classes mutable  wherever possible. It's just more robust all around. This is the reason String, BigInteger, LocalDate, etc. are all immutable classes.

Comment: There's no built-in way to deep copy in any way. This is because there's no standard way to create a true copy of a class. Only `data` classes have a standardized `copy()` function, but since `data class` is not an interface, there's no function for creating deep copies of lists of data classes. Even then, a deep copy might not be truly deep, because the data class might in turn be referencing some mutable class. But if you have a list of a data class, you could use `map { it.copy() }` to get a copy that is one layer deep.